# Changing the starting value in dropdown menu

Tags: php

So, I have a drop down menu that starts from 25000 to 3,000,000, increased by 25,000 each time.

```
<option  <?php selected('3000000', isset($_GET['max']) ? $_GET['max'] : ''); ?> ><?php _e('No Max', 'my_site') ?></option>
  <?php
    for($i=0; $i<=3000000; $i+=25000) {
    echo '<option '. selected($i, isset($_GET['max']) ? $_GET['max'] : '') . ' value='.$i.'>'.number_format($i, 0).'</option>';
    }
  ?>
```

At this point, however, the `"No Max"` gives the value of "0" as that is the starting value.
However I need this to be "3,000,000" instead of "0" when no selection is made.

Could someone help me out with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you add `selected="selected"` as an attribute inside the `<option>` tag you want to be the default choice (3,000,000 in this case), it should show that option as the default.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you be able to show me how to do it?